# Adding multiple index to optimize a query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am new to query optimization, I have a query that I wanted to optimize by adding non clustered indexes to it.

My query

```
SELECT t.*, t2.t7
FROM table t 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as t7
     FROM table t2
     WHERE t2.id = t1.id 
       AND t2.datetime < t.datetime  
       AND t2.datetime > DATEADD(day, -7, t.date)) t2 
ORDER BY
    id, datetime
```

To optimize this query I tried adding 3 indexes because of the where condition and order by clause, one after another

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_1
ON transactions(id ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX2
ON transactions(datetime ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX3
ON transactions(id,datetime ASC)
```

I have seen faster results after adding the third index, so my question here is: should I have created all three indexes to get faster results, or just the third index alone?

Answer (score 0):

The third index is the only index you need for this query.

The first index is totally redundant with it, in the sense that any query that can use that index can use the third one as well.

The second might be useful for other queries, but is not useful for this one (well, it would be if the outer query filtered on the date column, but that is not the case with the query you posted).